# Checking CR calculation for homebrew larger version of Giant Ape

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, cr-calculation

I am considering allowing a larger version of a Giant Ape, in which some of the stats have been embiggened to achieve the low end of CR8.

I would appreciate a confirmation that I am calculating this correctly.

In particular, it appears that what the DMG calls Damage Per Round, what is actually being assessed is **average** damage per round, **assuming that the maximum number of most damaging attacks hit.**

CR7 Giant Ape
AC12, 157hp (15d12+60), At. 2 @ +9 to hit, 3d10+6 dmg, DPR 45

CR8 Proposed Giant Ape [all other stats as RAW Giant Ape]
AC13, 168hp (16d12+64), At. 2 @ +9 to hit, 3d12+6 dmg, DPR 51

CR7 Giant Ape Calculation
Hp 146-160 = CR6, AC is more than two below 15, adjust DCR -1 to 5
DPR 45-50 = CR7, to hit is more than two above +6, adjust OCR +1 to 8
Average CR 6.5, [round to](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174252/how-to-interpret-round-up-or-down-in-monster-cr-calculation) CR7

CR8 Proposed Giant Ape Calculation
Hp 161-175 = CR7, AC is two below 15, adjust DCR -1 to 6
DPR 51-56 = CR8, to hit is more than two above +6, adjust OCR +1 to 9
Average CR 7.5, round to CR8

Comment: Given the negative response to this question so far, have I misunderstood the purpose of the cr-calculation tag?

Comment: Your related questions, linked for others' benefit: [Are there any official CR 8 beasts that are not dinosaurs, for the purpose of the Polymorph spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177997/33569), [Embiggening monster for higher CR for Polymorph (Homebrew)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177987/33569)

Comment: So the question is whether your calculation is in line with the DMG values? That's not difficult to check, I'm just ascertaining whether that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Anagkai Yes.  One question is whether I cam doing the _calculations_ correctly, which I think is straightforward.  The other is whether I am using the correct values.  For example, the passage in the DMG says "read down the Damage / Round Column", but AFAICT, never defines how one obtains the value for DPR of a monster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The calculation looks correct

I do not see any problems, neither logical nor mathematical nor from misusing the table.

### The damage calculation is explained under the step *Damage*

It seems your confusion about how the DPR is calculated comes from the fact that you just read *STEP 4: FINAL CHALLENGE RATING* (DMG p. 274-275) which explains how to translate a damage value to a CR. The determination of the damage value is performed like you assume which is explained on DMG p. 278 in the part named *STEP 11: DAMAGE* which says under *Overall Damage Output* (emphasis mine):

> To determine a monster's overall damage output, take the **average damage** it deals with each of its attacks in a round and add them together. If a monster has different attack options, use the monster's **most effective attacks** to determine its damage output.

Comment: So "average damage" means average damage _assuming it hits_?  That is, it is not pro-rated for the attack bonus?

Comment: @Kirt Yes. Variation based on to-hit chance would be factored into the To Hit column of the CR table and the associated correction.